# TestNG TestLink Jenkins Ant cannot find results

Tags: ant, jenkins, testng, testlink

I've just began to work with TestLink but I cannot see the results of the executions: on my Jenkins I have an ANT build file which runs a TestNG suite, and it began to work writting that he had found 1 result. (In spanish:

```
Ejecutado por el programador
Ejecutando remotamente en  qaie9 en el espacio de trabajo c:\jenkins\jobs\COMPLEMENTARIO
Preparando la API cliente del TestLink
Utilizando la siguiente URL del TestLink: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc.php

Ha encontrado 1 resultados de pruebas.

Ordenando casos de prueba automatizados por el orden de ejecuci?n del plano de pruebas del Testlink.

Ejecutando Build Steps unitarios.

[COMPLEMENTARIO] $ cmd.exe /C '"C:\apache-ant-1.8.3\bin\ant.bat testBasicoAgenda && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Buildfile: c:\jenkins\jobs\COMPLEMENTARIO\build.xml

testBasicoAgenda:.....
```

But at the end of the log, it says that he found 0 results:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 54 seconds
Ejecutando Build Steps iterativos.

Buscando por los Resultados de Pruebas de los Casos de Prueba del Testlink.

Looking for test results in TestNG methods by its name and data provider name.

Ha encontrado 0 resultados de pruebas.

TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/test-output/testng-results.xml
Saving reports...
Processing 'C:\Documents and Settings\usuarioqa\.jenkins\jobs\AGENDA - PLAN BASICO\builds\2013-03-21_17-30-44\testng\testng-results.xml'
TestNG Reports Processing: FINISH
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I mean, why doesn't it look for any TestNG results? The path for the results is `test-output/*.xml`. I've read another issue where somebody says It worked with success results and not for failed results but in my case it doesn't work with any! Can anyone help me please? I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: if I change the path of the testng-results.xml for another one which doesn't exist, It gives me the same response, How is it possible? It cannot find the file but it says nothing!

Answer (score 0):

The result found is the test case (with automated execution) in testLink.
Plz give your entire configuration of jenkins and your folder architecture.

Comment: Now I have it Jean Louis! Thanks very much! It was that I have not the right configuration of the Java Class name in the test case in TestLink.